# strcat() without null character

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[30] = "First";
    char str2[6] = "Second";
    strcat(str1,str2);
    printf("%s",str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is "FirstSecondFirst"
when I change `str2` size 6 to 7, it functions properly.

I know that it continues to read without stopping if there is no null char, but I don't understand why the word 'First' is repeated.

Comment: Lucky stack layout.

Comment: Would you understand if the result was `"FirstSecond$#@$@#!"`? Or `"FirstSecond----"`? Or `"FirstSecondThird"`? Or `"FirstSecond<CRASH-BLUE-SCREEN`?

Comment: This is all undefined behaviour. `str2[]` is too small to contain the string it is intialized to, let alone the concatenation.

Comment: `str2` is not a string because it has no null terminator.  You may not pass it to any of the standard functions that expect a null-terminated string as the argument.  That covers most functions in the standard C library — specifically `strcat()` but also functions such as `strlen()` and so on.

Comment: @bc a, "I know that it continues to read without stopping if there is no null char" --> Attempting read via  to `str2` from outside `str2[]` is not "continues to read".  It is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Anything may happen.

Answer (score 6):

Your `str2` variable is *not* a string, since it does not allocate space for a null terminator. As such, passing it to `strcat` results in undefined behavior.

Given what you've seen, the likely situation you've encountered is that `str2` is located immediately before `str1` in memory. Because `str2` is not null terminated, attempting to concatenate it to `str1` loops back into `str1` and concatenates `"first"` back onto `str1`. It stops because it *does* then encounter a null-terminator.

This particular behavior is just one possibility with [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) and should not be counted on to repeat in any predictable manner.

You might also test this by simply printing `str2` as a string without the concatenation, though as undefined behavior, it is not guaranteed to do the same again, so this *may* not be a useful test.

By allowing space for 7 characters in your fix, `str2` is initialized with a null-terminator and is a valid string. As such, no undefined behavior is incurred.

If you wish to allocate a string exactly as much space as needed, you can simply not specify the dimensions of the char array.

```
char str2[] = "second";
```

This correctly allocates 7 characters.